# Rounding "total hours spent" on a task to the nearest value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime

I am doing a case study to determine the total number of hours participants have slept per day. I've done some calculations and got the following column named "total_hours_sleep".

```
> df_daily_sleep_hours$total_hours_sleep
  [1]  5.4500000  6.4000000  6.8666667  5.6666667 11.6666667  5.0666667  6.0000000  5.4166667
  [9]  6.0166667  7.1666667  4.6166667  4.0833333  6.1000000  5.6833333  6.7333333  6.1500000
 [17]  4.6166667  4.5500000  4.1166667  5.5666667  5.5166667  9.9000000  5.6333333  6.3833333
 [25]  4.7500000  1.9833333  2.0666667 13.2666667  2.2833333 10.7333333 12.0333333  9.8333333
 [33] 12.5000000  6.6333333  7.9166667  4.9333333  2.7666667  8.3833333  8.8500000  9.0833333
```

Above values shows the number of hours the participants have slept per day. I wouldn't want to show the values for hours as `5.45 hours slept`, but instead to `6 hours slept`. Even for cases like `4.11 hours`, I still like to put the value down as `5 hours`. Hope this makes sense? For example, I would like to show number of hours as follows:

1. 5.45 hours -> 6 hours
2. 5.06 hours -> 6 hours
3. 4.19 hours -> 5 hours
4. 2.06 hours -> 3 hours and so on...

Is there a function in R that allows for this to happen?

Comment: `ceiling()` probably?

Comment: Ah thank you so much, just found out about that function and it worked!!!